# Jquery remove created Tabs and recreate them

Tags: jquery, html, tabs

This whole day has been a living hell for me. I'm working with Jquery ui to create Tabs for a website that shows some text with five progress bars. I can create the progress bars objects just fine without tabs.

Filling a div with  to create tabs for the first time brings no problems at all. All of the tabs are created and shown perfectly as shown below.

[image]

Now the problem is refilling the whole tabs with new  elements and progress bar objects. I've searched and tried so much answers, even a lot from StackOverflow, to try to refill this tab. I just can't figure it out. Every answer I try results in no tabs shown, just all the progress bar objects underneath each other or just plain error messages in the element inspector.

Here is the part of the code that creates new tabs (be warned, a day full of stress, disappointment and anger makes for ugly code)

```
function GetRatings()
{
    for(var i = 0; i < localStorage.length;i++)
    {   
        var rateItem = $.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem("rating" + (i+1)));

        if(rateItem != null)
        {
            if(rateItem.bossName == $('.reviewName').text())
            {
                $('.allRatingsBox').append("<div id = singleRate "+ i +"><p>" + rateItem.raterName + " rated: </p><div class = lBar>leadership:" + rateItem.leadership + "</div><div class = pBar>professionality:" + rateItem.professional + "</div><div class = fBar>fairness:" + rateItem.fairness + "</div><div class = cBar>charisma:" + rateItem.charisma + "</div><div class = uBar>understanding:" + rateItem.understanding + "</div><p>" + '"' + rateItem.comment + '"' + "</p></div>");
                $('.ratingTabholder').append("<li><a href=#singleRate" + i + "> </a> </li>");

                $(".lBar").attr('class', 'lBar' + i);
                $(".pBar").attr('class', 'pBar' + i);
                $(".fBar").attr('class', 'fBar' + i);
                $(".cBar").attr('class', 'cBar' + i);
                $(".uBar").attr('class', 'uBar' + i);
                $("#singleRate").attr('id', 'singleRate' + i);

                $( ".lBar" + i ).progressbar({ value: parseInt(rateItem.leadership)*10 });
                $( ".pBar" + i).progressbar({ value: parseInt(rateItem.professional)*10 });
                $( ".fBar" + i).progressbar({ value: parseInt(rateItem.fairness)*10 });
                $( ".cBar" + i).progressbar({ value: parseInt(rateItem.charisma)*10 });
                $( ".uBar" + i).progressbar({ value: parseInt(rateItem.understanding)*10 });

                $(".lBar" + i + " > div").css({ 'background': 'Blue' }); 
                $(".pBar" + i + " > div").css({ 'background': 'Green' }); 
                $(".fBar" + i + " > div").css({ 'background': 'Red' }); 
                $(".cBar" + i + " > div").css({ 'background': 'Orange' }); 
                $(".uBar" + i + " > div").css({ 'background': 'Purple' }); 


            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

It may not bring anything important with it, but here is the tiny part of my html code

```
    </div>
        <div class="allRatingsBox"> 
            <ul class="ratingTabholder">

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Lastly, after a whole day of trying to figure this out, this is my recent code to try to empty the tab element

```
function RemoveTabs()
{

    for(var i = 0; i < localStorage.length;i++)
    {   
        var rateItem = $.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem("rating" + (i+1)));

        if(rateItem != null)
        {
            if(rateItem.bossName == $('.reviewName').text())

                $( "#singleRate" + i).remove();
            }
        }
        $(".ratingTabholder").empty();
        $( ".allRatingsBox" ).tabs( "refresh" );
    }
```

This is what it looks like after the first time the Tabs are made, removed, and recreated

[image]

Why doesn't it create a perfect tab like the first picture. Why drop everything underneath each other? I hope you guys can help me. If there is something missing that you want to see, or if I have to explain it more properly, then let me know. I'm incredibly dull at this moment so some things might be wrong or misinterpreted.

Answer (score 1):

I've only had a brief look at your code but noticed a few errors in the Javascript.

1)  operator should be !== for both instances of the following statements

```
if(rateItem != null)
```

2) your parseInt calls need a second parameter for specifying the base.

```
$( ".lBar" + i ).progressbar({ value: parseInt(rateItem.leadership, /*put base here*/)*10 });
$( ".pBar" + i).progressbar({ value: parseInt(rateItem.professional, /*put base here*/)*10 });
$( ".fBar" + i).progressbar({ value: parseInt(rateItem.fairness, /*put base here*/)*10 });
$( ".cBar" + i).progressbar({ value: parseInt(rateItem.charisma, /*put base here*/)*10 });
$( ".uBar" + i).progressbar({ value: parseInt(rateItem.understanding, /*put base here*/)*10 });
```

Could be simple errors like these?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. After many hours of trial and error I found the perfect scope for removing ratings, removing tabs, getting ratings and refreshing tabs.

```
$( ".allRatingsBox" ).children("div").remove();
RemoveTabs();
GetRatings();
$( ".allRatingsBox" ).tabs( "refresh" );
```

Comment: nice! glad you found a solution :D